# Google calendar data is not showing in day view in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to show my google calendar schedule in my system using `fullCalendar` library. I had done all the steps as it is mentioned in the `fullCalendar` documentation. And it is working for week and month view. But for day view those schedule are not showing.
This is how I am integrating the calendar.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'googleCalendar','interaction', 'resourceDayGrid', 'resourceTimeGrid', 'bootstrap' ],
  themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
  defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
  },
  events: {
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'I am giving my calendar api here',
    googleCalendarId: 'giving calendar id here',
    className: 'gcal-event' 
  }
});
calendar.render();
});
```

Version of my `fullCalendar` is 4.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console, or network tool? Did you follow _all_ the instructions at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/google-calendar? Is your API key and ID correct? Does your Google calendar actually have any events in it (I kid you not, this has been an issue in the past!). Have you double- and triple-checked all of the above? We have no way of knowing what the issue is, the actual code itself looks fine, so presumably you've missed something elsewhere in the setup.

Comment: I had reviewed network. I can see if day view is called then items are not getting fetched. I have calendar data that's why those showing in week and month view. And about missing something elsewhere. I had used the fresh setup following all the instruction mentioned in the doc. In the library demo pages, I did not found any example with day view. Not sure if I am not finding or there are no demo for day view. Could you please guide me.

Comment: Sorry I must have misread the bit about day view, apologies. Once the data is loaded in the calendar it doesn't matter which view you use. If there is event on that date (and it falls within any restrictions e.g. minTime and maxTime, all day slot being visible) then it will be shown. If that's not the case...it's tricky to say why. Can you reproduce the same issue with any non-google event data? Also you're not running the latest version of fullCalendar...have you tried upgrading in case a bug has been fixed?